# How do I fix my right mouse buttonwhen it's not working on my Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, mouse, dell-latitude, right-click, mouse-click

The mouse present on my Dell Latitude 7390 has worked fine up until this morning, until I can no longer use the right mouse button on my touch pad. I am running windows 10, and I use the default windows drivers. The left mouse button and the track-pad work just fine. I use the right button a lot, so I find its absence debilitating. Any help on the issue would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does a mouse work? The trackpad might have malfunctioned and may need to be replaced. Also, on most trakcpads, 2 finger short tap can be used as a right-mouse button substitute.

Comment: Run the Dell Hardware diagnostics - all tests.  You probably have to replace the keyboard.

Comment: @John, the buttons are a separate assembly from the keyboard. sold by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how, create a live USB install disk for Windows or a Linux distro.  If the touchpad's right button does not work in that, its a hardware issue.  If it does work, then its a software issue of some kind in the Windows installed on the hard drive.  It could be a configuration of the touchpad's settings or some piece of software has take control of the right click.  First things first, test the button on another OS, like a USB live installer.

Comment: Suggesting using another OS is valid, but you should include the fact that these buttons are easily replaced, if hardware is at fault.

Answer (score -1):

If an **external** mouse right button works, then consider switching to one.

However, it could be there are OS issues, such as faulty drivers. Try [installing the latest drivers from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000107587/latitude-7390-windows-10-driver-pack).

If that doesn't work, then there are tutorials for replacing the buttons, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfbdPslGSwY), and parts are advertised, such as from [Parts-People](https://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=category&id=140&subid=1270&refine=mouse%20button) or [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Dell+Latitude+%227390%22+replacement+mouse+button).

Comment: An external mouse would be using a different driver.  If the right mouse button didnt work, it could be several different issues, not just hardware.